# Unable to use --screenshot or --print-to-pdf using headless mode of Chromium on Ubuntu desktop

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, chromium, headless, google-chrome-headless

I am using the headless version of Chrome and Chromium to take screenshots of given pages.
It works fine on Windows and Ubuntu server, but not on an Ubuntu Desktop VM.

I get the error "**Open multiple tabs is only supported when remote debugging is enabled**" on Ubuntu Desktop when I try to take a screenshot (`--screenshot` flag) or to generate a PDF file (`--print-to-pdf` flag).

I could enable remote debugging with the `--remote-debugging-port` flag, but when it is enabled, you can not use the `--screenshot` flag or the `--print-to-pdf` flag.

Any ideas on how I could use these flags on Ubuntu desktop ?

## Details

### On windows

**Version** :
Google Chrome Version 84.0.4147.125

**Command used** :
`> start chrome --headless --screenshot=%CD%\example_sh.png https://example.com/`

*Note: you have to give a path to the screenshot on windows or else it will not create the file, this is why I added `%CD%\` on Windows only. But this is not the issue here.*

**Command output** :
None

**File generated :**
`Yes`

### On Ubuntu Server

**Version** :

```
$ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 84.0.4147.105 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04
```

**Command used** :
`$ chromium-browser --headless --screenshot=example_sh.png https://example.com/`

**Command output** :
`[0812/102830.971006:INFO:headless_shell.cc(615)] Written to file example_sh.png.`

**File generated :**
`Yes`

### On Ubuntu Desktop

**Version** :

```
$ chromium-browser --version
Chromium 84.0.4147.105 snap
```

**Command used** :
`$ chromium-browser --headless --screenshot=example_sh.png https://example.com/`

**Command output** :
`[0812/123941.367535:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(174)] Open multiple tabs is only supported when remote debugging is enabled.`

**File generated :**
*`No`*

---

Note that a solution consisting of replacing .deb packages is not what I want.  This could be a good workaround if I were the only one using these flags, but this won't do as a solution, as I'm calling a command using them inside some code that is part of a library that is shared with other people.

Comment: I have opened an [issue on bugs.chromium.org](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1115618) about this error, but I am still unsure if this is a bug or not.
My project is stuck because of this problem, so I placed a bounty on this question if someone can ever provide solution.

Comment: It sounds to me like chromium-browser is aliased/wrapped in a way that makes it look like there are two non "--" arguments, so it thinks you want an additional page as well as example.com, if you leave out the website maybe it runs and you get an image of a customized start page or something?

Comment: @lossleader indeed, if the website is left-out, it runs and generates a blank image (white background only with default size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

1. open chromium interactive with:
   `chromium-browser https://example.com/`
   or if that fails just `chromium-browser`.
2. Go to `chrome://version` in a tab in this new session and note **Command Line** and **Executable Path**.
3. Look for unusual spaces in the command line, such as from an argument with a file path that is not properly escaped. (This can be added to the question and issue after sanitizing any usernames/etc.)
4. Using the binary indicated in **Executable Path** directly try to construct your `--headless` command. If the cause was from a wrapper this should work, if not, using that binary interactively, look at the chrome://version -> **Command Line** again. There may not be a good workaround if the mangling comes from things it is compiled to inject in to its own command line.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. `Executable path` is the key to the solution. Using it instead of the `chromium` or `chromium-browser` command does not cause any errors. The executable path displayed on the chrome://version page is `/snap/chromium/1260/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome`, but it also work with /snap/chromium/`current`/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome. I am wondering if it is possible to find the value of this `executable path` via command line? If you happen to know a way to do this I would be glad to hear it. Thanks again :)

Comment: sure, if you do "file -L `which chromium`" that's hopefully a distribution specific script, probably the problem line (and line specifying this binary) is an exec line at the bottom. you could use sed to make a repaired copy of the script to run or extract it. If the source of the extra option isnt in this script you could also add an `echo $@` to look at what it is being called with. But in any case I would update the issue with an example of the commandline when running with snap vs the working server since the bug might not be simple to reproduce, i.e. depend on $homedir paths, etc.